# Transfer data from HTML page 1 to HTML page 2 when submit is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, forms

I don't know how to transfer data from one page to another when I hit submit after typing

page 1================================

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form action="page2.html">
        <h1>page 1</h1>
        <div id="name">
            <label>name</label>
            <input type="text" name="N">
        </div>
        
        <input id="submit" type="submit" >
    </form>
    
    
    <script src="page.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

page 2 ===================================

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>page 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>page 2</h1>
    <div id="data">
      <h1>NAME : <span id="dataName"></span></h1>
    
    </div>
    <script src="page.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

I tried to use it in  javascript

```
let resultName = document.querySelector("input[name='N']");
let result = document.getElementById('submit');

result.onclick = () =>{
    console.log(resultName.value);
    resultName.value = dataName;
    let dataName = document.getElementById('dataName').innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: if you're using JS, why have 2 separate "pages" and not just have 1 page with the content in the page dynamic?

Comment: One way is through the `form` tag (GET method). Then on the subsequent page you can grab the querystring and parse it for the data you want to send

Answer (score 0):

In order to get form data from one page to another page you need to store the form data in the local storage and from local storage get the data and render it on the second page.
It is not possible to get the form data directly to the second page, it is because when the user clicks on the submit button to proceed to the second page there will be a reload for the second page and the previous page i.e form page gets removed from the DOM.